# Get user input from set list in python

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to interact with an API that has inputs that can only be a certain thing. Let's say they can be 'apples', 'oranges', 'pineapples'

I'm trying to create input so that the user can only chose from one of those values. Say I have a list

user Options = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pineapples']

I can make it so if the users input doesn't match one of those it throws up an error but ideally I want it so the user can just press the down arrow and it cycles through the available options and shows the user which option they are choosing as opposed to just an index from userOptions. Any code wizards out there able to help?

Comment: What is the user pressing a down arrow on? [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your question is a little bit unclear about the type of input you want to use. The code I added below is very simple and uses normal keyboard input to cycle through the options. Check it out:

```
# Valid options
opts = ["apples", "oranges", "pineapples"]
print("\nThe possible options are:", *opts, "\n")

# Selection loop
selected = opts[0]
while True:
    print("Selected option is:", selected)
    print(" n: select next option")
    print(" c: continue with selected option")
    pressed = input("> ")
    print()
    if pressed=="n":
        selected = opts[(opts.index(selected) + 1) % len(opts)]
    elif pressed=="c":
        break

# Out of selection loop
print("The selected option is:", selected)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.  Sorry I'm a total amateur so find I struggle to use the right terminology.  Either way thanks for being a constructive contributor.  The code you have written should provide me with a really useful building block to work from.  Thank you for your help.